# Databind or pass object to web user control property .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I'm honestly not sure if databinding is the correct technique to achieve this, so if anyone could enlighten me I would be most grateful.

Basically what I'm trying to do is pass an object from the current page into a web user control as such (code simplified):

**ExamplePage.aspx**

```
<div>
    <EC:AttachmentsView ID="AttachmentsView1" Attachments=<%# this.PageAttachments %> runat="server" />
</div>
```

**ExamplePage.aspx.cs**

```
public partial class ExamplePage : ProductBase
{
    private LinkItemCollection _pageAttachments;
    public LinkItemCollection PageAttachments
    {
        get { return _pageAttachments; }
    }

    public ExamplePage()
    {
        this.Load += new EventHandler(this.Page_Load);
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Accessing and assigning attachments (EPiServer way)
        _pageAttachments = CurrentPage["Attachments"] as LinkItemCollection ?? new LinkItemCollection();
    }
}
```

The attachments view control has setters and getters for the `Attachment` and `Label` properties.

**AttachmentsView.ascx.cs**

```
namespace Example.Controls
{
    [ParseChildren(false)]
    public partial class AttachmentsView : EPiServer.UserControlBase
    {
        private string _label;
        public string Label
        {
            get { return _label; }
            set { _label = value; }
        }

        private LinkItemCollection _attachments;
        public LinkItemCollection Attachments
        {
            get { return _attachments; }
            set { _attachments = value; }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_attachments == null)
            {
                _attachments = CurrentPage["DefaultAttachments"] as LinkItemCollection ?? new LinkItemCollection();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm at the stage where I would expect the page attachments from the ExamplePage to be passed into the AttachmentsView control but the _attachments property is null.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Is databinding the right technique, if so does anyone know material which explains the concepts easier than the horrible MSDN documentation?

I know I can probably achieve this by programmatically rendering the control but I'd like to try this method first.